# Twitter Api - Rate Limits - friendships/destroy

Tags: api, twitter

In this page https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/friendships/destroy you can read that the POST friendships/destroy is rate limited.
But this other page https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits don't report the rate limit for friendships/destroy request.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You're right - and doing an application/rate_limit_status doesn't show this, nor do the x-rate-limit-Xxx headers.

Comment: Were we able to determine if it's indeed rate limited?

Comment: Erick Smith Joe Mayo Think you're right too 4 this comments. There is a rate limit in (x-rate-limit-Xxx) doesn't show nothing of this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with this too.  Here's what I found:

"POST / create endpoints are feature limited on a per-user basis. For instance, a user can post 2400 tweets per day, broken down into hourly intervals. These are documented on the Support pages7. Since these limits vary and may be more fluid for operational reasons, there is no equivalent list of POST endpoints with their rate limits listed out."

https://twittercommunity.com/t/403-forbidden-through-api-for-every-follow/22566/5

Comment: Right Manager_of_it "POST / create endpoints are feature limited on a per-user basis. For instance, a user can post 2400 tweets per day, broken down into hourly intervals. These are documented on the Support pages7. Since these limits vary and may be more fluid for operational reasons, there is no equivalent list of POST endpoints with their rate limits listed out." it's good and you link too, but there's not a file that explain this. Struggled more then U.